# Build and deploy executable without any dependency on project files c#

Tags: c#, console-application, publishing

I have a **c# console application project** which is being called from command line because is taking arguments from command prompt.

My questions is how can I publish my executable without any dependency on project files. For example if I publish my executable to C:/myFolder, but only executable without any other files or folders, I want to be able to run it from there.

Comment: [Any  Suggestions?](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2014/10/missing-stackoverflow-topic-terrible-question/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application uses only the .net framework and has no other dependencies, you should be able to just deploy your compiled `.exe` file to where ever you need it provided that you have installed the correct version of .net framework.

Comment: That is exactly what i thought, but once I publish my app trough visual studio, It is not anymore myApp.exe it is becoming myApp.application. And i cannot call it from command prompt for some reason.

Comment: How do you have compiled and published you application? Could you list up the deployed files

Comment: BUILD>Publish select a folder to publish your app, and that is pretty much everything I have done.

Comment: Ok, i have never used this method of deploying an application. I've always used `WiX Toolset`.

Comment: Well obviously i have used wrong method of deploying my app, and this is actually what i was looking for, thank you very much for your help!